# allow domain in httpd.conf file block rule

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, httpd.conf

I have a "rule" in `httpd.conf` to pop-up a windows if somebody tries to access `wp-admin` section of any domain where wordpress is installed. With this rule I prevent boots for accessing wp-admin folder and to stop brute forces attacks.

```
# BEGIN BLOCK-WP-ADMIN-ATTACK

<Files wp-login.php>
AuthType basic
AuthName "EN: Human Check - U: human P: letmein"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /home/wp-admin-attack-htpasswd-file
Require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 "<center><h1>Warning!</h1>You failed to authenticate.<p><br />Extra security has been temporarily enabled due to an ongoing attack against Wordpress logins on this server.<br /> <b>If you are a real user, please refresh the page and enter the username and password that are provided on the pop-up.</b><p>If you are still having troubles, please contact your hosting provider.</center>"
</Files>

# END BLOCK-WP-ADMIN-ATTACK #
```

This rule is working as it should but now I want to "allow" a domain so this rule will not apply for that domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) to do this. This is untested but might point you in the right direction:

```
# set env ALLOWED if hostname is either example.com or
# the client ip is 192.168.0.1
SetEnvIf Host example\.com ALLOWED
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 192.168.0.1 ALLOWED

# if ALLOWED is not set display the password prompt
<IfDefine !ALLOWED>
  <Files wp-login.php>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "EN: Human Check - U: human P: letmein"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /home/wp-admin-attack-htpasswd-file
    Require valid-user
    ErrorDocument 401 "<center><h1>Warning!</h1>You failed to authenticate.<p><br />Extra security has been temporarily enabled due to an ongoing attack against Wordpress logins on this server.<br /> <b>If you are a real user, please refresh the page and enter the username and password that are provided on the pop-up.</b><p>If you are still having troubles, please contact your hosting provider.</center>"
  </Files>
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: i tried it and it didn't worked for me (apache 2.4)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `satisfy any` instruction

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# [ Server Domain ]
ServerName the.domaine.allowed
# [ Server Root ]
DocumentRoot /var/www/
# [ Pass Through Auth]
<Files wp-login.php>
satisfy any
</Files>    
<VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to `satisfy any`. This is a working proof-of-concept:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
            Satisfy Any

            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from example.org

            AuthType basic
            AuthName "EN: Human Check - U: human P: letmein"
            AuthBasicProvider file
            AuthUserFile /home/wp-admin-attack-htpasswd-file
            Require valid-user
            #ErrorDocument here
</Files>
```